# In symfony2, how to restrict access to a specific ROLE even if access is allowed when IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, access-control

I'm using FOSUserBundle and I have two ROLES: ROLE_A and ROLE_B. I want ROLE_A to be restricted to a specific area, for example /admin :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/test/, roles: ['ROLE_B', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'] }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_A }
```

Using this access_control, only ROLE_A has access to /admin, but now, when a user is connected as ROLE_A, I don't want him to be allowed to see /test.
I may use for each controller something like this :

```
public function testAction()
{
    if (true === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_A')) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

    // ...
}
```

But with a lot of controllers, I don't think this is a good idea...
Do I need to use several firewalls or ACL ? because I don't feel it's necessary...

Comment: Why do you have `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` for `/test`?

Comment: I don't want to restrict access to /test. Anyone can see /test except if user is connected as ROLE_A

Comment: Did you find a way to restrict access based on a ROLE? AFAIK you can only *grant* access based on roles, not do the opposite.

Comment: The project is over now but I did not find how to do this.